# How to iterate over a collection of one to many relation in datamapper orm

Tags: codeigniter, orm, datamapper

I have two classes

```
class Product extends DataMapper {
    var $has_one = array('category');
}
class Category extends DataMapper {
    var $has_many = array('product');
}
```

I need to get the all the products for the category and its sub-categories. Any suggestions.

Category table looks like this:

```
id - int(11), parent - int(11), name - varchar(100), slug - varchar(100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498943/datamapper-self-relation-model). Basically this is a one-to-many relation and can be achieved by implementing self-relationship.

Thanks anyways..!!